# AWS Lamba, multi tenant apps, sepatate databases

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, multi-tenant

I have to create app where each user has his own database, can login on his own subdomain, but all users use the same API endpoints (Lambda functions).

API is in Node.js, Frontend in Angular 7.

Is it feasible? Can you give me instruction how to configure AWS to it?

Answer (score 1):

AWS has little role to play. Your nodejs api and lambda functions design will handle this

Comment: the main challenge for me is to use separate databases for each user. Do you have any suggestion how to do it in node.js?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this a couple of years ago. I used a key called `ClientID` which is passed into every request. You can use anything as long as it's unique.

In your APIs, when you initialize your database, use that identifier to map your database connection. (this means you have to initialize the database each time there's a request)

e.g.

User A -> Database A

User B -> Database B

etc...

However, I encountered an issue when doing this:

> when you update database A, you have to update database B as well.
>   (what happens when you have 100 databases?)

But it's doable.